# Spring Kafka integration test class fails if not executed first

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, testcontainers

I wrote following integration test class:

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
class DomainCourseMapperServiceApplicationIntegrationTest {

    @Container
    static final KafkaContainer kafkaContainer =
            new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.4.3"));

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void overrideKafkaProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);
    }

    private static final String SCHEDULE_RAW_TOPIC = "schedule.raw";
    private static final String SCHEDULE_DOMAIN_TOPIC = "schedule.domain";

    KafkaTemplate<String, ScheduleRaw> scheduleRawProducer;
    Consumer<String, ScheduleDomain> scheduleDomainConsumer;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        ProducerFactory<String, ScheduleRaw> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProps);
        scheduleRawProducer = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);

        Map<String, Object> scheduleDomainConsumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps(kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers(), "schedule-domain-test-group", "false");
        scheduleDomainConsumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        scheduleDomainConsumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        scheduleDomainConsumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        scheduleDomainConsumerProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");

        ConsumerFactory<String, ScheduleDomain> scheduleDomainConsumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(scheduleDomainConsumerProps);
        scheduleDomainConsumer = scheduleDomainConsumerFactory.createConsumer();
        scheduleDomainConsumer.subscribe(List.of(SCHEDULE_DOMAIN_TOPIC));

    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        scheduleDomainConsumer.close();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldConsumeScheduleRawAndProduceMappedScheduleDomainToDomainTopic() {
        // Given
        ...

        // When
        scheduleRawProducer.send(SCHEDULE_RAW_TOPIC, key, event);
        ConsumerRecord<String, ScheduleDomain> result = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(scheduleDomainConsumer, SCHEDULE_DOMAIN_TOPIC, Duration.ofSeconds(20));

        // Then
        ...
    }

}
```

When this test class is executed alone it passes, but the problem occurs when this test class is not run alone and I get following stack trace in output of test:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No records found for topic

at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(KafkaTestUtils.java:181)
```

When test class is executed with other test classes (in project except this test class there are no other integration test classes - only unit tests) it fails, but only at one condition - it mustn't be executed first. If this test class is executed first and then other test classes it passes.

I added breakpoint on the line where event is handled in `SCHEDULE_RAW_TOPIC` consumer to see if event is received and the breakpoint has not been triggered - so there are two possibilities: problem with `scheduleRawProducer` or with the consumer.

I also tried adding `@DirtiesContext` on top of test class but it didn't resolve the problem.

Has anyone faced similar problem or knows what could be the solution?

---

Comment: `If this test class is executed first and then other test classes it passes.` - it looks like there are some other test which essentially "steals" data from this test. So, `@DirtiesContext` must be added to that test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Artem wrote in his comment the solution was adding `@DirtiesContext` - in question I mentioned that I have already tried placing `@DirtiesContext` on the class but I put it as the last annotation (the first from the bottom).

After placing: `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` as a first annotation from the top on the class problem was fixed.